# How to handle multiple conditions in 1 if statement?

Tags: r, if-statement

I am comparing a 20-day moving average against a 50-day, 100-day 200-day and 333-day. The condition is essentially just

```
if(20MA > 50MA > 100MA > 200MA > 333MA) {
  return TRUE
} else{
  FALSE
}
```

Is there a way in R to handle this without multiple nested if statements?

```
if(tail(MA_20,n=1) > tail(MA_50,n=1) > tail(MA_100,n=1) > tail(MA_200,n=1) > tail(MA_333,n=1)) {
  score[1] <- 1
} else{
  score[1] <- -1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&&` (see `help("&")` for other logical operators)

```
if (tail(MA_20,n=1) > tail(MA_50,n=1) &&
    tail(MA_50,n=1) > tail(MA_100,n=1) &&
    tail(MA_100,n=1) > tail(MA_200,n=1) &&
    tail(MA_200,n=1) > tail(MA_333,n=1)) {
    score[1] <- 1
} else {
    score[1] <- -1
}
```

The `if` statement will return true if all four of those comparisons are true.

The `ifelse` function might be helpful for you in speeding up your code as it helps vectorize comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

The following way seems more complicated but is more flexible. It first gets all variables named after the pattern `"MA_"` and `sapply` the `tail` to extract the last element. Then uses `diff` to see if they are in decreasing order.

First make up some data.

```
library(zoo)

set.seed(1234)    # Reproducible results
n <- 1e3
x <- rnorm(n)

MA_20 <- rollmean(x, k = 20)
MA_50 <- rollmean(x, k = 50)
MA_100 <- rollmean(x, k = 100)
MA_333 <- rollmean(x, k = 333)
```

Now the problem.

```
score <- NULL

ma <- stringr::str_sort(ls(pattern = "^MA_"), numeric = TRUE)
MA_last <- sapply(ma, function(m) tail(get(m), n = 1))
score[1] <- if(all(diff(MA_last) > 0)) 1 else -1
```